# The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) in .netcore 3.0 on Linux

Tags: c#, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, .net-core-3.0

I just created a simple "Hello World" console app to start testing .netcore 3.0 development on Linux using VS Code, and it won't compile with (currently) 26 errors, mostly stating that predefined types System.Object, System.String, System.Void etc are not defined or imported.

The .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Project Include="Program.cs"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The Program.Main

```
using System;

namespace TestNetCore3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

What's interesting is I have the same problem with a classlib I've been working on, which compiles and runs (the tests) fine when on a Windows 10 machine, yet when I load the repo on my Linux machine it all falls apart at the seams.

Comment: thats weird, can you check you have dotnet runtime/sdk installed. can you run `dotnet --info` it will tell you which runtimes and SDK do you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had both 3.0.100 and 2.2.402 SDKs installed, which was causing a conflict. Uninstalling 2.2.402 did the trick

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.402
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice idea will be to check if you have instaled specified SDK, in this case for .NET 3.0.

You can do this by typing:

> dotnet --list-sdks

for all installed SDK versions, or like it was pointed in comment by **TiGreX** by using :

> dotnet --info

Also keep in mind, that for 3.0 Visual Studio Code require newest C# extension, so please check if you have it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have SDK versions 3.0.100 and 2.2.402 installed, and no new updates available for VS Code or any of my extensions (including C#). Could it be that I need to uninstall the 2.2.402 SDK? Might it be interfering?